# Button with 100% of background image size

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a button with 100% of an image's width and height without specifying the width and height on the button.

eg: If I change the image, the button size should be changed dynamically as well according to the size of the image

Note: The button size should be exactly the image size without stretching/distorting/enlarging/shrinking the image. If I change the image to 300px * 200px, the button size should be 300px * 200px as well.

Is it possibly to be done with css alone?

```css
#rock {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/CeJU3mO.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button id="rock"></button>
```

Comment: @MichaelCoker both does not fit my intended need. What i mean is if i change the image to 300px * 200px, the button should change to 300px * 200px exactly as well without without stretching/distorting the image.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't just make the image a hyperlink? In other words `<a href=""><img src="..."></a>`, and forgo the button.

Comment: @Michael_B coding standard in company. It is an image button therefore it should be declare as an html button instead of div, img etc.

Comment: @stackdisplay my bad, didn't read your question carefully enough. Gave you another answer. I think you're looking for `<input type="image">`

Comment: @MichaelCoker if the OP is intending on using this with a form and php with POST/GET arrays, an input image type won't pass those. This being a sidenote of course. Then again, that may work with js/ajax though; hard to say what they want to use it for.

Comment: With CSS, you can easily make the image stretch to button size, backwards is kinda more complicated, you can convert the button into a block, but it won't take the size of a background image. If the image were an `<img>` inside a `<button>`, I think that could be possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the image with a pseudo element and make it hidden to hold the size.

```css
#rock {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/CeJU3mO.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0;
}

#rock:before {
  content: url("https://i.imgur.com/CeJU3mO.png");
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="rock"></button>
```

Apart from background, you can also use inline image inside the button.

```html
<button id="rock"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/CeJU3mO.png" alt="Button"></button>
```

Otherwise use `<input type="image" src="...">` instead.

```css
input[type="image"] {
  outline: 1px solid; /*demo*/
}
```

```html
<input type="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/CeJU3mO.png">
```

Note, that image has some blank edges by default.

Comment: I really like these pseudo elements ... upvoted ... and can't wait (and hope) until we can chose to have them render as either a child or a sibling ... or both :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an element match a `background-image`'s size without explicitly setting the element height to match the image.

You can use `<input type="image">` which is a graphical submit button, and the `input`'s size will match the dimensions of the image.